# iOS Sqlite NSDate value

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a **Date** column in my Sqlite database. When I put some `NSDate` value in it, and open the Sqlite file through graphical tools. I get some value like **530963469.705571**. The corresponding date is around today or yesterday.

It's clearly not Unix epoch datestamp value. **What exactly does this value mean?**

I need to change this value in order to debug my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Date to SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165033/saving-date-to-sqlite)

Comment: @ImadAli Not the same question. My codes work fine. I just need to know what is this value so I can change it.

Comment: There is no date type in SQLite, so what is the type of your `Date` column?  Also, it would obviously help if you show us the code you have for writing to this column.  As of now, I suspect this is more of an iOS question than a SQLite one.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate)

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001).

Since sqlite does not support `NSDate` directly, the date is persisted as the underlying value. 530963469.705571 represents the number of seconds between 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001 and the time when you created the `NSDate`

You can use the `NSDate` initialiser `init(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:)` to create an `NSDate` from the time interval value.

Comment: Now I figured it out. It's **Seconds Since 0001-01-01 AD**. By the way, I created `Data Model` file, and created an `entity`, and created a `attribute` which I can select a `Date` type. Thanks!

Comment: You generally would use `timeIntervalSince1970` instead of `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:`, as you can then use the `unixepoch` option in the SQLite date functions/tools to display the date in a user-friendly format.