# how to save current date to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, sqlite

I create a sqlite database. 'Orders' is a table that has idOrder(int), dateOrder(varchar) and discount(float). In Bill.h, I set dateBill as NSDate, so how can I save current dateBill into table 'orders'?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this subject was also covered here. [Persisting Dates to SQLite3 in an iPhone Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251155/persisting-dates-to-sqlite3-in-an-iphone-application)

```
+ (NSDate *) dateWithSQLiteRepresentation: (NSString *) myString;
{
    NSAssert3(myString, @"%s: %d; %s; Invalid argument. myString == nil",  __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    return [[self sqlLiteDateFormatter] dateFromString: myString];
}

+ (NSDate *) dateWithSQLiteRepresentation: (NSString *) myString timeZone: (NSString *) myTimeZone;
{
    NSString * dateWithTimezone = nil;
    NSDate * result = nil;

    NSAssert3(myString, @"%s: %d; %s; Invalid argument. myString == nil",  __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSAssert3(myTimeZone, @"%s: %d; %s; Invalid argument. myTimeZone == nil",  __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    dateWithTimezone = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@ %@", myString, myTimeZone];
    result = [[self sqlLiteDateFormatterWithTimezone] dateFromString: dateWithTimezone];
    [dateWithTimezone release];

    return result;
}

+ (NSString *) sqlLiteDateFormat;
{
    return @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";    
}

+ (NSString *) sqlLiteDateFormatWithTimeZone;
{
    static NSString * result = nil;

    if (!result) {
        result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@ zzz", [self sqlLiteDateFormat]];
    }

    return result;    
}

+ (NSDateFormatter *) sqlLiteDateFormatter;
{
    static NSDateFormatter * _result = nil;

    if (!_result) {
        _result = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [_result setDateFormat: [self sqlLiteDateFormat]];
    }

    return _result;
}

+ (NSDateFormatter *) sqlLiteDateFormatterWithTimezone;
{
    static NSDateFormatter * _result = nil;

    if (!_result) {
        _result = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [_result setDateFormat: [self sqlLiteDateFormatWithTimeZone]];
    }

    return _result;
}


- (NSString *) sqlLiteDateRepresentation;
{
    NSString * result = nil;

    result = [[NSDate sqlLiteDateFormatter] stringFromDate: self];

    return result;
}

- (NSTimeInterval) unixTime;
{
    NSTimeInterval result = [self timeIntervalSince1970];

    return result;
}

#define SECONDS_PER_DAY 86400
#define JULIAN_DAY_OF_ZERO_UNIX_TIME 2440587.5
- (NSTimeInterval) julianDay;
{
    return [self unixTime]/SECONDS_PER_DAY + JULIAN_DAY_OF_ZERO_UNIX_TIME;
}

+ (NSDate *) dateWithJulianDay: (NSTimeInterval) myTimeInterval
{
    NSDate * result = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Also You can refer this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302664/objective-c-and-sqlites-datetime-type

Answer (score 0):

datatype of column is INTEGER

For Saving date:

sqlite_bind_double(compiledStatement,1, [yourdate TimeIntervalSince1970]);

For retrieve date:

NSDate *gotDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 1)];

Hope it helps

Regards

Kuldeep